# Filling Fermions into the Lowest Landau Level and the Laughlin Wave Function

Tags: quantum-hall-effect

For a particle moving in the $xy$-plane in the presence of a uniform magnetic field $B$ along the $z$-direction, if one chooses the symmetric gauge of the vector potential, then one can use the simultaneously diagonalize the Hamiltonian $H$ and the $z$-component $L_z$. The lowest Landau level wave functions are

$$
\phi_m(z) \propto z^m e^{-|z|^2/4}, \quad m = 0, 1, 2, ...
$$

where $-m$ is the eigenvalue of $L_z$.

The Laughlin wave function for $N$ electrons assumes that the electrons will fill states with the smallest $m$; therefore the $N$-electron wave function is (by anti-symmetrizing the states with $m = 0,1,...,N-1$ and using properties of the Vandermonde matrix)

$$
\Psi(z_1,...,z_N)
= \prod_{i < j}^N (z_i - z_j) e^{-\sum_{i=1}^N |z_i|^2/4}
$$

My question: why electrons in reality will fill in the states with the lowest (magnitude of) eigenvalue of $L_z$? On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laughlin_wavefunction), it is said that this is related to the Coulomb interaction between the electrons, and the background positive charges (the jellium), but no details are provided. Please explain *quantitatively* (using some toy models), or kindly provide references to articles or texts that actually did some calculation.

Comment: If the particles had a *contact* interaction (modelled by a delta-function) instead of a long-range Coulomb interaction, then the Laughlin is the state with lowest total angular momentum to reach an eigenvalue of **zero** for the contact interaction. Since every real system has some edge effects (a harmonic trap, the actual edge of a heterostructure etc) then low total angular momentum will always win, since low total angular momentum = smallest effective radius of the electron cloud.

Comment: CONTINUED: Now, the Laughlin state has electrons located at local density minima with respect to the other electrons, so they very effectively shield eachother (this is sometimes called "dressing" electrons in vortices/flux tubes, see e.g. Jain's composite fermions) and so this effect carries over to the Coulomb interaction even though the expectation value is now finite (non-zero).

Comment: References: Jain's first chapters in *Composite fermions*, the reviews of S. Viefers or N. Cooper about the link between bosonic/fermionic QHE systems.